# using symmetry or geometry for a double integral $\iint_D (4-\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}+\sin(xy))dA$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Using either geometry or symmetry, evaluate:
>
> $$\iint_D \left(4-\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}+\sin(xy)\right)dA$$ where $D$ is the disk with $r=3$ centered at $(0,0)$.

---

[**What I did**] I separated them to 3 integrals.

- For the first integral I got 
  $4$ times the area of $D$.
- The second one I got volume of the hemisphere with radius $3$
- and the last is I believe a value of $0$ by symmetry.

So I get a total of $18\pi$. I am not sure about the first integral since I realized that if I am getting the area of D then I can't just combine it with the volume I found from the second integral. This is my observation, however I am not really sure. Please help.

Comment: Your approach is fine.  Think of $z=4$ as a plane and you are calculating the volume of a cylinder.  Does that work for you now?

Comment: What does "if I am getting the area of D then I can't just combine it with the volume I found from the second integral" mean?

Comment: I meant, I got a value in terms of area for the first integral and a value in terms of volume for the second integral. So they must not have the same unit of measurement so I can't combine them. That's why I am not sure if I did right with my first integral.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a coherence in term of physical dimensions between your three integrals you can interpret these as:
$$
4\int\int_Df(x,y) dA+\int\int_Dg(x,y) dA+\int\int_Dh(x,y) dA
$$
where $z=f(x,y)=1$ is the height at a point $P=(x,y)$ of a plane parallel to $\{x,y\}$ plane, $z=g(x,y)=\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}$ is the height of a spherical cup and $z=h(x,y)=\sin(xy)$ is the height of a sort of symmetric ''flover'', all the heights measured from the $\{x,y\}$ plane. So all the terms we are adding are volumes.

Answer (score 0):

I think what confuses you is how one can add two different quantities with different units of measurement together. No, we can't. For example, it makes no sense to do
$$
1 cm^2+4 cm^3
$$

But in the calculation of an integral, you don't have such problem. When you calculate $\iint_D4\ dA$, you got a *number* without any [unit of measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_measurement); though, you can interpret it as the "area" of $D$.

Comment: Also, I think that I made a mistake of using the formula for a circle as the area for D. I am really confused of the first integral.